# Best way to use Moveit for teleoperation?

Tags: manipulator, collision, avoidance, cartesian, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this topic discussed a bit [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/74776/cartesian-controller-for-ros/), and on the MoveIt! mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/teleoperation/moveit-users/YMRbLxZ6uyM/q3LbqCux6Q4J) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/teleoperation/moveit-users/B3_CBZtsG1c/kpOjoc6dU5MJ), but those conversations are pretty old now and I'm wondering if there is a clearer answer now.

I have a 7 DOF arm I would like to teleoperate. I plan on using a 3D mouse to command the Cartesian motion of the end effector and  utilize the redundancy of the arm so the whole arm avoids collisions with itself and the environment. By *teleoperation* I mean that as I push the 3D mouse forward for example, the end effector moves forward seemly in real-time, then when I release the mouse the motion stops. I think guarded fly-the-gripper is a term that best describes it. If I had to guess I would say an update rate of 30Hz would be plenty fast. Right now I'm simplifying things by not using any hardware - only simulating in MoveIt using a simple environment (e.g. a single block to reach around).

I assumed that MoveIt's most popular use case of plan-then-execute position control wouldn't suffice, I'm guessing that giving discrete positions as input would not provide the streaming/constant motion I desire. I jumped in trying to implement something from scratch using KDL's velocity inverse kinematics solvers but quickly realized that MoveIt does a lot of really useful stuff under the hood that I wasn't utilizing that I'm not sure how to implement for velocity control. I decided I better take a step back and ask for help before getting to deep.

Does anyone have any advise on doing something like this? Do those above posts still hold true or is there new capabilities I should be aware of? Maybe you know of an open project that has done something similar? Let me know if I should provide more information about what I've tried so far.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226958/best-way-to-use-moveit-for-teleoperation?/) by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3460 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to look at the [trac_ik](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) ROS package, either in whole or any of the individual parts.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-02-18**:
Thanks for the advise, I went ahead and installed and tried out the trac_ik solver and it does seem to do a better job than KDL, but I'm not really having problems with IK. I'm having problems understanding the best way to do live/streaming teleop using MoveIt's architecture.

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2016-10-21**:
Hi, I am trying to do the same .. did you make any progress.. I could use some help here ... :)

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-10-25**:
Unfortunately no, I didn't make any progress on this.

**Comment by [zeroos](https://answers.ros.org/users/25654/zeroos/) on 2017-01-18**:
Hey guys, just bumping the question. Did any of you manage to come up with some working solution? I was thinking about providing small position changes to moveit, but I am worried the movements might not be very smooth...

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-01-18**:
@zeroos I am not working on it nowadays but if you are interested we can work together and come up with a solution. Let me know if you are inetersetd.

**Comment by [zeroos](https://answers.ros.org/users/25654/zeroos/) on 2017-01-19**:
@ZainMehdi yeah, if you have any suggestions/ideas I would be more than happy to hear about them!

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-01-19**:
@zeroos Please share your email ID. I will start working on it again and will update you about my progress. It would be nice to hear from you too :)

**Comment by [zeroos](https://answers.ros.org/users/25654/zeroos/) on 2017-01-19**:
@ZainMehdi I have actually found this paper in one of the links provided at the beginning of the question: http://workshops.acin.tuwien.ac.at/clutter2013/papers/ric2013_paper_8.pdf . It summarizes the problem nicely. I think I'd try to follow the MP solution and see how fast it can get on my robot.

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-01-19**:
@zeroos That would be great. let me know how it works out.